# jQuery Bootgrid sort doesn't work - POST variable inconsistency

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having somme issues when trying to order the data on my jQuery bootgrid. Data is obtained and filtered on server side. No issues there, however whenever I press a column name to otder the data I can see on the console that instead of getting a sort[name-of-field] I receive sort[{{ctx.column.id}}] which makes it impossible to read (when I'm parsing the sort variable).

```
<table id="clienteData" class="table table-condensed  table-bordered table-striped" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th column-data-id="cod_cliente"  data-identifier="true" data-formatter="COD_CLIENTE" data-sortable="true">CODIGO</th>
<th column-data-id="nombre" data-formatter="NOMBRE">NOMBRE</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

This is the function that's run at the begginning and sets everything in order:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Inicializa  = function() {
        $("#clienteData").bootgrid("destroy");
        $("#clienteData").bootgrid({
        ajax: true,
        rowSelect: true,
        labels: { noResults: "No hay resultados" },
        post: function() {
          return { id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"  };
        },
        url: "DatosClientes.php",
        formatters:{
          "COD_CLIENTE": function(column, row) { return row.COD_CLIENTE;},
          "NOMBRE": function(column, row) { return row.NOMBRE;}
        }
      })
    }
    Inicializa();
    });
```

When I receive the sort variable in the DatosClientes.php, I check the value at the console and what I receive is :

[Variables received on "DatosClientes.php"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKT3Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was so easy, and after days of debugging....

I had to replace column-data-id with data-column-id

Now works fine!!